# htaccess - Run url if correct rewrite

Tags: .htaccess

I try to rewrite rule url in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^myfolder/([^/]*)$ /myfolder/index.php?link=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^myfolder/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /myfolder/functions.php?model=$1&id=$2&method=$3 [L]
```

So, it works. But, my css is not loading. I tried to find some solution and when i change:

```
<link href="css/colors/blue.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

to

```
<link href="css/blue.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and remove blue.css from "css/colors" folder and add it to "css" folder. My css is loaded.
My question is How to load css in "css/colors/blue.css".

Comment: Did you tried with <base href="/">.

Comment: RewriteBase / like  <base href="/">.

Comment: No inside your html head tag.

Comment: i meant if i use RewriteBase / in .htaccess, it will be like i use  <base href="/"> in html.

Comment: Tks. I had a solution: create new file .htaccess in css folder and turn off rewrite with "RewriteEngine Off"